# Gnome-keyring login problem

Tags: 16.04, login, password, startup, gnome-keyring

Why the Keyring fails most mornings when I start my desktop?

Currently I have to enter my one and only password several times at start up as I detail below. What am I doing wrong?

I am using `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS` and have installed `gufw firewall`.

In Startup Applications I edited the descriptions so that Keyring is first, hoping that might authenticate gufw and other apps. 
No luck ; I still must enter password again, a second time .

Then I removed gufw from the Startup Applications

Searched for "com.ubuntu.pkexec.gufw" and opened it with gedit:
None of these details help me as an end user

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">;
<policyconfig>

  <action id="com.ubuntu.pkexec.gufw">
    <message gettext-domain="gufw">Authentication is required to run the Firewall Configuration</message>
    <icon_name>gufw</icon_name>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/gufw-pkexec</annotate>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">true</annotate>
  </action>

</policyconfig>
```

I also get "System program problem" with one or more of these in details:

```
com.ubuntu.pkexec.gufw

com.ubuntu.apport.apport-gtk-root

/usr/sbin/cupsd
```

I must authenticate each time with my one password.

Online Accounts also pops up at start up for me to grant access for Google to integrate with Evolution Email and Contacts.

Comment: I just realised that I have had AutoLogin on forever. Now changed it to OFF and hope that fixes some of the above symptoms. 
Thanks Yaron for advice about avoinding personal contact details. They were on an email that I sent to ubuntu-users@lists.ubuntu.com. I got no response there.

Comment: AskUbuntu wins again. I changed AutoLogin to OFF as advised in another posting; now most of the repeated popups wanting a password have stopped, hopefully forever.

Answer (score 0):

By setting my login to Autologin OFF and removing Gufw from Startup Applications my login hassles stopped. Only one password is needed to get going.
Apologies for not reading previous answers carefully enough.